# labelFor in JavaFX 1.3

Tags: label, javafx

I'd like change the state of a JavaFX 1.3 `CheckBox` when the user clicks on the label associated with it. The [documentation of the `Label` control mentions the `labelFor` property](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/javafx/javafx/1.3/docs/api/javafx.scene.control/javafx.scene.control.Label.html):

> Label is a non-editable text control. A Label is useful for 
>   displaying text that is required to fit within a specific space, 
>   and thus may need to use ellipses or truncation to size the string 
>   to fit. Labels also are useful in that they can have mnemonics 
>   which, if used, will send focus to the Control listed as the target
>   of the `labelFor` property.

I've tried the following:

```
var autoRefreshCheckBox : CheckBox = CheckBox {
    ...
}

var autoRefreshCheckBoxLabel : Label = Label {
    text: "Autorefresh"
    labelFor: autoRefreshCheckBox
}
```

Unfortunately it does not compile:

```
[WARNING] ...fx:347: cannot find symbol
[WARNING] symbol  : variable labelFor
[WARNING] location: class javafx.scene.control.Label
[WARNING] labelFor: autoRefreshCheckBox
[WARNING] ^
```

Any idea?

Comment: it seems it's an error in javadoc as same page doesn't state `Label` has `labelFor` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a text to the checkbox and it handles the onclick event.

```
 var autoRefreshCheckBox : CheckBox = CheckBox {
            text: "Autorefresh"
 ..
```

}